# Intellij: Search through the source of maven dependencies in a project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Is it possible to search for a bit of text through the source code of all the maven dependencies of a project?

For example: If you import the following sample maven project: https://github.com/ajorpheus/javadoc-mem-test/tree/search-in-jars, searching for `tempHeaders` should turn up `AbstractClientHttpRequest.java` as a search result.

Is there a plugin that allows one to do this?

If Intellij does not support this, would you know of an IDE-agnostic way to do this given a maven project? I have looked at tools like [jarexplorer](https://code.google.com/p/jar-explorer/downloads/detail?name=jarexplorer-0.7-BETA.jar&can=2&q=) but they don't seem to do the job.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I found how to do this !

Use the 'Project and Libraries' Custom Scope.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

in IntelliJ IDEA 2018, you can do this: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

[image]

thanks [@Ashutosh Jindal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325742/ashutosh-jindal)

Comment: I actually tried doing this but cannot seem to search for logging statements inside third-party library dependencies. If I open the class file of a third-party library I definitely see the text there though...

Comment: @HiChews123 Are you looking at the third-party library content by decompiling? Or is it an open source project?

Comment: i am pulling in dependencies through maven, and the dependencies are open-source

Comment: Under normal circumstances, IDEA will help download the source code of the open source library, you can see the source package that IDEA to help you download? @HiChews123

Comment: Good updated answer, thanks. I note that for each result line of the search, we could not see the dependency related to. It is very cumbersome in some cases.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your requirement correctly, what you are trying to do is possible.

First in the Maven pane you need right click on dependencies and select 'Download Sources'.

Once that is done, follow Ashutosh Jindal instructions to search in your code and the dependencies code.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. There is two way to search in Intellij.

**1. Ctrl + shift + F**

**2. navigate - > search everywhere or use Ctrl + N**

To search in external libraries , you have to make sure they are downloaded first in your system then only you can search anything among them.

Comment: For  the  first option, u need to change  the  scope  to "Project and Libraries" the  default scope  won't  work

Answer (score 1):

For IntelliJ 2020 go to the main menu, select Navigate | Search Everywhere or press Shift twice to open the search window.

For more information check here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html#search_all

[Search everywhere example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sczZW.gif)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the source from maven tool bar